# Simple Ajax request in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, coffeescript

I have a small server running on localhost:8083

I tested a `put` request with [Chrome postman client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

```
http://localhost:8083/addcompany?{"Ticker":"Hello", "Name":"Hello, Inc."}
```

which translates in

```
POST /addcompany?{"Ticker":"Hello", "Name":"Hello, Inc."} HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8083
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

and correctly returns:

```
{
"Ticker": "Hello",
"Name": "Hello, Inc."
}
```

I have tried to implement the same request in my client app.

```
postTicker = (tkr, name) ->
    console.log "posting #{tkr}, #{name}"
    aCompany = JSON.stringify ({Ticker:tkr, Name: name})
    console.log aCompany
    queryUrl =  encodeURI 'http://localhost:8083/addcompany'
    $.ajax queryUrl,
        type: 'POST'
        timeout: 5000
        data: aCompany
        success: (response) ->
            #parsedResponse = $.parseJSON response
            alert response
            #removeAddBtn (parsedResponse.ticker)
        error: (response) ->
            console.log "AJAX Error: #{response}"
```

The request results in the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function
```

for `data: aCompany`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to stringify your data. Could you try to change the third line of your javascript:

**from**:

```
aCompany = JSON.stringify ({Ticker:tkr, Name: name})
```

**to**:

```
aCompany = {Ticker: tkr, Name: name}
```